# FBX export problem with over 150 milion triangles

Tags: export, .fbx

I have a very huge scene with over 150 million triangles, just polygons and image texture, and I need export it to a fbx file, but it give me a traceback error and a 14kb fbx file.

The traceback message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\blender\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 638, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
  File "D:\Program Files\blender\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3225, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
  File "D:\Program Files\blender\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3129, in save_single
    encode_bin.write(filepath, root, FBX_VERSION)
  File "D:\Program Files\blender\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 287, in write
    elem_root._write_children(write, tell, False)
  File "D:\Program Files\blender\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 234, in _write_children
    elem._write(write, tell, (elem is elem_last))
  File "D:\Program Files\blender\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\encode_bin.py", line 214, in _write
    write(pack('<3I', self._end_offset, len(self.props), self._props_length))
struct.error: argument out of range
```

Finally I use 3dSMax to export it and succeeded but I don't know why I get that error.

My pc got 32GB memory and setup 160GB virtual memory.